# App Engine naked domain redirect + SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps

We are trying to add naked domain redirect to our custom domain. I followed the instructions on https:/ /support.google.com/a/answer/2518373?hl=en
but when I change the domain to redirect from:
http:/ /app-id=,domain=.example.io (which was auto filled)
to http://www.example.io, I get an error saying:
"""
Server error
We are unable to process your request at this time, please try again later.
"""
I'm not able to dig any deeper into the error or what is happening. My A records on the DNS provider point to the IP address specified by the App Engine. I also have SSL on this app, and https://www.example.io works fine. Its only https://example.io that gives me "Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" error.

Answer (score 3):

It seems SSL on naked domains is not currently supported by App Engine. We have a similar issue, so our naked domain redirects to `http://www.~` which then redirects to `https://www.~`

You might like to take a look at (and star) [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10802).

Answer (score 2):

Best free SSL redirect service I found was [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/). To get it working:

1. Add your domain and switch your name servers to CloudFlare (signup process walks you through it)
2. Once added goto CloudFlare Settings and down to SSL. Change the setting to 'Full SSL (Strict)' this requires you to have a valid cert on the subdomain your redirecting to (SNI works fine).
3. Go back to your websites list, select the domain again and on the options goto page rules. Add a 'Forwarding' rule that redirects `https://yourdomain.com/*` to `https://www.yourdomain.com/$1` (replace www with any subdomain), make sure the redirect is set to 301.
4. Save your settings and sit back and wait for everything to propagate.

Done. Free and secure SSL redirection for your naked domain.

Answer (score 2):

As of September 2015, [SSL is supported on naked domains by AppEngine](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10802#c33).